# Remove required validation for belong_to attribute on Rails 5

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I remove the required validation for belong_to attributes on Rail 5.

Now, I am having an error like below when I try to save a model with a nil value on belong_to attribute
`User must exist`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/config/initializers/active_record_belongs_to_required_by_default.rb` file

change

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

to

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

for some reason, it may not works. For fix it, you have to add this setting to each environment in `config/environments/.....rb`

**OR**

just add to your association option `optional: true`

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

Comment: I think the last alternative is better. Thanks

Comment: if you add option, you skip this feature just for one association, in first case you skip it for entire project